# javascript countdown echoing wrong time

Tags: javascript, html, countdown

i want this my javascript code to to be able to be reading 3 hours countdown and also redirect to a new page after the countdown is complete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// properties
var count = 0;
var counter = null;

window.onload = function() {
initCounter();
};

function initCounter() {
// get count from localStorage, or set to initial value of 1000
count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000;
counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
}

function setLocalStorage(key, val) {
if (window.localStorage) {
  window.localStorage.setItem(key, val);
}

return val;
}

function getLocalStorage(key) {
return window.localStorage ? window.localStorage.getItem(key) : '';
}

function timer() {
count = setLocalStorage('count', count - 1);
if (count == -1) {
  clearInterval(counter);
  return;
}

var seconds = count % 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 60;

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours +  "hours "  + minutes  +  "minutes and "   + seconds +  "  seconds left to complete this   transaction"; // watch for spelling
 }
</script>
<div id="timer"></div>
```

please help me make it better by making it been able to countdown to three hour and also redirect to another page after the countdown is complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't properly set total time. You set it to 16 minutes instead of 3 hours. Here is the working code (try it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4wut0po/)):

```
var time = 60 * 60 * 3;
var div = document.getElementById("timer");
var t = Date.now();

var loop = function(){
  var dt = (Date.now() - t) * 1e-3;

  if(dt > time){
    doWhateverHere();
  }else{
    dt = time - dt;
    div.innerHTML = `Hours: ${dt / 3600 | 0}, Minutes: ${dt / 60 % 60 | 0}, Seconds: ${dt % 60 | 0}`;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

loop();
```

Also, do not use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` for precise timing. These functions are volatile. Use `Date.now()` instead.

Comment: i just want you to help me check where i will make it three hours without changing my code.

Comment: @phemieny7. `count = getLocalStorage('count') || 3600 * 3` instead of `count = getLocalStorage('count') || 1000`. But I **strongly** recomment you not to use `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions in this case.

Comment: yeah i love your code, but the problem i got with it is that it restart when the page is refreshed. if you can correct that, i will really love to use it. Please help me correct that. Thanks.

Comment: @phemieny7. Of course, it restarts because JavaScript is client-side language. The only way to continue counting after page refreshs is using cookies. I am sure you can find a way to do it if you read a wiki.

Comment: @phemieny7. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it. Thanks.